# How to fix esp-idf build error for "esp_heap_alloc_caps.h" and "freertos/heap_regions.h"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, heap-memory, esp32, freertos

I'm getting started with inter-task communication with FreeRTOS on an esp32 by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLqj01asDM0&themeRefresh=1) from pcbreflux but I can't build the example with esp-idf in VS Code because two of the header files raise a `No such file or directory` error:

```
#include "esp_heap_alloc_caps.h"
#include "freertos/heap_regions.h"
```

After some research, I found that `"esp_heap_caps.h"` can replace `"esp_heap_alloc_caps.h"` (*Can someone confirm that?*) and this indeed removes the part of the compilation errors. But `"freertos/heap_regions.h"` is still giving me problems. Even if I add this header file manually I get an `undefined reference to xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged` compilation error. I guess that means this function has been dropped in favor of another implementation. **What should I be using instead?**

Here is my `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
        },
        {
            "name": "ESP-IDF",
            "compilerPath": "c:\\Users\\arthu\\.espressif\\tools\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\esp-2021r2-patch5-8.4.0\\xtensa-esp32-elf\\bin\\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "includePath": [
                "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espAdfPath}/components/**",
                "${config:idf.espAdfPathWin}/components/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPath}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espIdfPathWin}/components",
                    "${config:idf.espAdfPath}/components/**",
                    "${config:idf.espAdfPathWin}/components/**",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false
            },
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` inside of my main folder:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "queue_main.c" INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` inside of my project folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(main)
```

And the `queue_main` example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sdkconfig.h"

#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_heap_caps.h"

#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "freertos/heap_regions.h"

#define COLOR_PRINT_BLACK "30"
#define COLOR_PRINT_RED "31"
#define COLOR_PRINT_GREEN "32"
#define COLOR_PRINT_BROWN "33"
#define COLOR_PRINT_BLUE "34"
#define COLOR_PRINT_PURPLE "35"
#define COLOR_PRINT_CYAN "36"
#define color_printf(COLOR, format, ...)                               \
    {                                                                  \
        printf("\033[0;" COLOR "m" format "\033[0m\n", ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    }

xQueueHandle demo_queue;

void tx_task1(void *arg)
{
    uint32_t txpos = 0;

    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_BLUE, "tx_task1");

    while (1)
    {
        color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_BLUE, "free DRAM %u IRAM %u", esp_get_free_heap_size(), xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged(MALLOC_CAP_32BIT));
        color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_BLUE, "tx_task1 notify %d", txpos);
        if (xQueueSendToBack(demo_queue, &txpos, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS) != pdTRUE)
        {
            color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_RED, "tx_task1 fail to queue value %d", txpos);
        }
        vTaskDelay(10000 / portTICK_RATE_MS); // delay 10s
        txpos++;
    }
}

void tx_task2(void *arg)
{
    uint32_t txpos = 0;

    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_CYAN, "\ttx_task2");

    while (1)
    {
        color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_CYAN, "\tfree DRAM %u IRAM %u", esp_get_free_heap_size(), xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged(MALLOC_CAP_32BIT));
        color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_CYAN, "\ttx_task2 notify %d", txpos);
        if (xQueueSendToBack(demo_queue, &txpos, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS) != pdTRUE)
        {
            color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_RED, "\ttx_task2 fail to queue value %d", txpos);
        }
        vTaskDelay(7000 / portTICK_RATE_MS); // delay 7s
        txpos++;
    }
}

void rx_task(void *arg)
{
    uint32_t rxpos;

    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_GREEN, "\t\trx_task");

    while (1)
    {
        color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_GREEN, "\t\trx_task queue yield");
        if (xQueueReceive(demo_queue, &rxpos, 60000 / portTICK_RATE_MS) != pdTRUE)
        { // max wait 60s
            color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_RED, "\t\tfail to receive queued value");
        }
        else
        {
            color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_GREEN, "\t\tfree DRAM %u IRAM %u", esp_get_free_heap_size(), xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged(MALLOC_CAP_32BIT));
            color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_GREEN, "\t\trx_task get queued value %d", rxpos);
        }
        if (uxQueueMessagesWaiting(demo_queue) == 0)
        {                                         // no message? take a break
            vTaskDelay(15000 / portTICK_RATE_MS); // delay 15s
        }
    }
}

void app_main()
{
    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_PURPLE, "start ESP32");
    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_PURPLE, "free DRAM %u IRAM %u", esp_get_free_heap_size(), xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged(MALLOC_CAP_32BIT));

    demo_queue = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(uint32_t));

    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_PURPLE, "free DRAM %u IRAM %u", esp_get_free_heap_size(), xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged(MALLOC_CAP_32BIT));

    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_PURPLE, "create three tasks");
    xTaskCreate(tx_task1, "tx_task1", CONFIG_SYSTEM_EVENT_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 5, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(tx_task2, "tx_task2", CONFIG_SYSTEM_EVENT_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 5, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(rx_task, "rx_task", CONFIG_SYSTEM_EVENT_TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 5, NULL);

    color_printf(COLOR_PRINT_PURPLE, "end of main");
}
```

Please let me know if I should provide more details.

Comment: Which IDF-version do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest: 4.4.3

Comment: Which development board do you use? Depending on the build target (MCU) specific libraries are not availble...

Comment: It's an ESP32-WROOM-32 dev board from Az-Delivery. I think the problem is that `xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged` has been deprecated in the esp-idf. I just don't know what to replace it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to old [documentation](https://demo-dijiudu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-reference/system/mem_alloc.html) for `xPortGetFreeHeapSizeTagged(BaseType_t tag)`:

```
Get the amount of free bytes in a certain tagged region.
Works like `xPortGetFreeHeapSize` but allows the user to specify a specific tag
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4.3/esp32/api-reference/system/heap_debug.html#heap-information) for 4.4.3 you could use `heap_caps_get_free_size(uint32_t caps)` instead of `xPortGetFreeHeapSize`...

```
Parameters:   caps – Bitwise OR of MALLOC_CAP_* flags indicating the type of memory
Returns:      Amount of free bytes in the regions
```

Those capabilities are defined in `esp_heap_caps.h`.
You could give `heap_caps_get_free_size(MALLOC_CAP_IRAM_8BIT)` a try.